# Is there asynchronous file i/o in Android NDK?

Tags: c++, android-ndk, aio

I had to save/load a lot of data stored at the sdcard in my C++ android-ndk code. However, I was told that there is no async file IO `<aio.h>` in Android NDK, is that right?

If so , can any of you give me an example (or guideline) of async read/write files in Android NDK? Thank you!

Comment: Just curios, Did you find some useful library or did you write your own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, there is no AIO available in the latest Android NDK:

```
$ cd ~/android-ndk-r15/platforms/android-26
$ find . -type f -exec grep aiocb {} \;
$
```

What is your primary use? Asynchronized reading or writing? You may have to roll your own solution with multiple threads.

Or search github for existing solutions to portable async IO.